# Simple Oracle query: literal does not match format string

Tags: oracle, sqlplus, date-format, ora-01861

I want to execute a simple function in Oracle. The signature is defined as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION NewCaseListForValidation
(
                             p_fromDate in DATE,
                             p_toDate in DATE,
                             p_rowCount in INT
)
RETURN
                             SYS_REFCURSOR
IS
                             return_value SYS_REFCURSOR;
...
```

I should be able to execute it with:

```
var rc refcursor
exec :rc := newcaselistforvalidation('2010-01-01','2011-01-01',100);
print :rc
```

But when typing "newcaselistforvalidation('2010-01-01','2011-01-01',100)", I get:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

I googled a bit and it seems I can't figure out to type the date in a correct format. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Query NLS_PARAMETERS in Oracle- you will then be able to see what format your DB is accepting dates in.

Typically however i use the to_date() function:

```
to_date('01-01-2011','DD-MM-YYYY');
```

In the UK to input my dates.

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to the to_date() function is to use the ANSI standard format for DATE or TIMESTAMP literals:

```
DATE '2010-01-31'
TIMESTAMP '2010-01-31 21:22:23'
```

Date and time is always specified using ISO rules (YYYY-MM-DD and 24hour format for time)

This also works on a lot of other (standard compliant) DBMS.

Answer (score 1):

> It's best not to rely on particular value in **NLS_PARAMETERS** settings,
> cause this will make your function **break** in the env with another **NLS_DATE_FORMAT**.
>
> I'd **explicitly specify date formatting** in your function as suggested in the answer above

```
exec :rc := newcaselistforvalidation(to_date('2010-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),to_date('2011-01-01','YYYY-MM-DD'),100);
```

Answer (score 0):

INSERT INTO tblDate (dateStart)
Values ('20-JUN-2013');
If you change month integer into a string 'DD-MON-YYYY' works as a valid data string without having to preface it with the DATE identifier.