# Oracle - literal does not match format string error

Tags: sql, database, oracle, date-format, ora-01861

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Simple Oracle query: literal does not match format string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884071/simple-oracle-query-literal-does-not-match-format-string)

I am getting the following error:

```
INSERT INTO CatalogueEntry VALUES('2001-12-10', 2, 14.99, 1, 0)

ERROR at line 1: ORA-01861: literal does not match format string `
```

The first field is a `DATE` format.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you are inserting a string value to a date column, then you need to convert it to a date during the `INSERT` using the [`to_date()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function. When using this function you will provide the format of the string.

`to_date()` function format:

```
to_date( string1, [ format_mask ], [ nls_language ] )
```

So your query will be like this:

```
insert into CatalogueEntry
values
(
  to_date('2001-12-10', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
  2,
  14.99,
  1,
  0);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cb00e/1)

Comment: Another alternative is to use an ANSI SQL literal: `date '2001-12-10'`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `date` literal depends on NLS_DATE_FORMAT settings thus cannot be an alternative solution to OP's problem.

Comment: @NicholasKrasnov: The ANSI date literals are completely independent of any NLS or other environment settings (it *has* to be `YYYY-MM-DD`). So this *is* a valid alternative (less typing and works across a wide range of DBMS actually)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Oh my, of course :). For some reason I mistakenly assumed opposite.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I was not aware that you can use an ANSI SQL Literal like that.  Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 1):

Try this SQL:

```
INSERT INTO CatalogueEntry 
              VALUES(to_date('2001-12-10','yyyy-mm-dd'), 2, 14.99, 1, 0);
```