# selecting data fom a view throws error

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I get input as `2011/11/13 00:00:00`. So I made the query as:

```
select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw 
where week_ending_date = to_date(substr(:value,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD')
```

The same statement gives proper result when queried against other tables. But throws error when I query this against the view xxcust_pfoa434p_vw

I have a view xxcust_pfoa434p_vw which has a column week_ending_date of date data type.
The value in that column is like `3/2/2014,12/25/2011 i.e. MM/DD/YYYY`

Even

```
select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw where week_ending_date='3/2/2014'
```

also gives
 ORA-01843: not a valid month. What is the cause for this error.

Comment: http://www.dbforums.com/oracle/1215287-ora-01843-not-valid-month-not-all-should.html

Answer (score 1):

You say

> "The same statement gives proper result when queried against other
>   tables. But throws error when I query this against the view
>   xxcust_pfoa434p_vw"

So clearly the problem is with the view.  You also say

> "[the view] has a column week_ending_date of date data type. The value
>   in that column is like 3/2/2014,12/25/2011 i.e. MM/DD/YYYY "

Those values would only display like that if the default date mask for you system were MM/DD/YYYY. This is easy enough to check with the query

```
select * from V$NLS_PARAMETERS
where parameter = 'NLS_DATE_FORMAT';
```

Personally, my money is on that column not being a date column.  `ORA-01841` always indicates oracle attempting to cast a string into a date and finding a value which doesn't fit the explicit or default format mask.  Plus the so-called date '3/2/2014' lacks leading zeroes and that's suspicious too.

I think whoever wrote that view decided to fix the format of `week_ending_date` and so deployed TO_CHAR to present a string not a date datatype.  A `DESC` in SQL*Plus or looking at the view TEXT in [ALL_VIEWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/statviews_2118.htm#REFRN20305) will reveal the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you see formatted date in this format - it is only a visual representation, when oracle process your query it automatically convers string given by you into its own interal representation.

It is always better to use proper SQL one YYYY-MM-DD:

**for 2nd march:** `select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw where week_ending_date = to_date('2014-03-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

**for 3rd february:** `select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw where week_ending_date = to_date('2014-02-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD')`

this conforms to SQL standard and do not produce confusion between `DD/MM/YYYY` and `MM/DD/YYYY`

Just quote from [standard](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~shadow/sql/sql1992.txt):

> There is an ordering of the significance of <datetime field>s. This
>   is, from most significant to least significant: YEAR, MONTH, DAY,
>   HOUR, MINUTE, and SECOND.

UPDATE: it is very good idea always use [to_date](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php) function to specify exact format and avoid dependancy on any kind of localization settings

Comment: I tried both and getting error"literal does not match format string"

Comment: @Gayathri looks like you have to use to_date, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13518506/oracle-literal-does-not-match-format-string-error

Comment: @Lashene I tried thie, but didn't work select *  from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw where week_ending_date = to_date('2013/11/13','YYYY/MM/DD')

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw 
where week_ending_date=to_date('03/02/2014','MM/DD/YYYY');
```

Comment: Sai, my query  select * from xxcust_pfoa434p_vw where week_ending_date = to_date(substr(:value,1,10),'YYYY/MM/DD') works fine with other table but not with the view. I tried the query which you have given. Getting error "ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"

Comment: Gayathri, First provide date format in the table from which you created view. try to use the same date format in the where condition of view.

Comment: one more thing use to_date(trim(:value),'YYYY/MM/DD')"