# SQL - literal does not match format string in INSERT INTO

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I've created an empty table--in my website that holds a bunch of tables-- that has the following columns/data types:

NAME -- VARCHAR2

MRN -- NUMBER

DATE_S -- DATE

E -- DATE

DELI -- DATE

WB -- VARCHAR2

ST_ID -- VARCHAR2

COMMENTS --VARCHAR2

EI -- NUMBER

Below is one of almost 800 rows of code I am using to populate the table.

```
INSERT INTO SANDBOX.W_C VALUES ('S,E',11300033,'2012-02-18 00:00:00','2012-03-01 00:00:00','2013-02-18 00:00:00','N','006i',NULL,NULL);
```

When I run that piece of code I get the following message: `literal does not match format string`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple Oracle query: literal does not match format string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884071/simple-oracle-query-literal-does-not-match-format-string)

Comment: @PaulL I've seen that question, but I still don't understand what is wrong with my code.

Comment: What's wrong with the code is precisely what was wrong with the other questioner's code - you need to use the `to_date` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you provide a date as a string, the database uses it's default settings to try to convert the string. The best way to handle this is the use of `to_date`, as in scaisEdge's answer.

However, you can also change the default date mask using `alter session` before you run the `insert` statements:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss';
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to_Date

```
   INSERT INTO SANDBOX.W_C VALUES ('S,E',11300033, 
   TO_DATE('2012-02-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),
   TO_DATE('2012-03-01', 'yyyy-mm-dd'), 
   TO_DATE('2013-02-18', 'yyyy-mm-dd'),'N','006i',NULL,NULL);
```

Comment: is there a faster way--I have almost 800 lines of similar `INSERT INTO...` code

Comment: the faster way is insert the value in dummy table with the date column like varchar and then populate the right table with a select that convert the varchar in date ..